# Can synchronized statements on different objects interleave?

Tags: java, locking, synchronized

I am studying the keyword `synchronized` and I do not understand if it's possible to have 2 synchronized statements in the same class to interleave; example:

I made a class with these simple methods and two lock objects:

```
public class Locker1 {  
    private Object lock1= new Object();
    private Object lock2= new Object();

    public void printL1() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            for(int i=0; i<50;i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

    public void printL2() {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            for(int i=0; i<50;i++) {
                System.out.println("-"+i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I made two different threads that just call `printL1` and `printL2`, in my understanding I thought since these are two different locks I would see positive and negative numbers printed alternatively because concurrency is possible, but I tried many times and `printL2` always happens entirely after `printL1`, not once I saw a negative between positive numbers, am I missing something on synchronized?

Here is the rest of the code

```
public class ThreadA extends Thread {
    private Locker1 l1;

    public ThreadA(Locker1 l1) {
        this.l1=l1;
    }

    public void run() {
        l1.printL1();
    }
}
```

```
public class ThreadB extends Thread {   
    private Locker1 l1;

    public ThreadB(Locker1 l1) {
        this.l1=l1;
    }

    public void run() {
        l1.printL2();
    }   
}
```

and main class:

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Locker1 l1=new Locker1();

        ThreadA tA=new ThreadA(l1);
        ThreadB tB=new ThreadB(l1);
        tA.start();
        tB.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show the code calling your print methods

Comment: Could you show us how you use the class?

Comment: @Lino ok added it I hope it's not too long

Comment: Did you try with more iterations? The 50 Iterations may simply be finished before the second Thread starts to run. Your Code looks fine

Comment: @codeflush.dev thanks, now I tried a whole 5000 iterations and I do see the interleaving;I tried before with 2 different printing classes and i just needed 10 numbers to see the interleaving so i thought they were enough for this case too

Comment: Funny enough, I've tried a thing with the code - moved `tB.start()` before `tA.start()`. However, positive numbers still appeared first. JVM does some interesting stuff behind the scene.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You understanding on Thread and Lock is correct. Since `Locker1.printL1()` and `Locker1.printL2()` grant the lock to different objects, One thread access `Locker1.printL1()` while another access `Locker1.printL2()` should not block each other.

The reason you see a complete printL2 result after printL1 is because the work is too little for the CPU. 50 iterations take a fraction of millisecond to complete. Before a [context switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch) is needed, the task is completed.

Let the task sleep for a small amount of time and you can see how the thread yield.

```java
public class Locker1 {
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void printL1() {
        synchronized (lock1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                System.out.println(i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void printL2() {
        synchronized (lock2) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                System.out.println("-" + i);
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(50);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

output:

```
0
-0
1
-1
2
-2
3
-3
4
-4
5
-5
6
-6
7
-7
8
-8
9
-9
10
-10
11
-11
12
-12
13
-13
14
-14
15
-15
16
-16
17
-17
18
-18
19
-19
20
-20
21
-21
22
-22
-23
23
24
-24
25
-25
26
-26
27
-27
28
-28
29
-29
30
-30
31
-31
32
-32
33
-33
34
-34
35
-35
36
-36
37
-37
38
-38
39
-39
40
-40
41
-41
42
-42
43
-43
44
-44
45
-45
46
-46
47
-47
48
-48
49
-49
```

Answer (score 1):

The interleaving happens as expected; it was hard to see with only 50 iterations, so putting in a lot more iterations shows it